# jquery/javascript Multiple Click functions will work in order they are coded

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

So I have a main div and 3 smaller divs to the right of it, each div contains an image. My goal is that when one of the smaller div images is clicked on it changes the content in the main div. I am able to do this but the second and third divs will not work unless the first div is clicked first. Once the first div is clicked then all the divs will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded

    $('#divright1').click(function(){
        $('#divmainleft').load('sidechange1.php #content', function() {
            $('#divright2').click(function(){
                $('#divmainleft').load('sidechange2.php #content', function() {
                    $('#divright3').click(function(){
                        $('#divmainleft').load('sidechange3.php #content', function() {
                            /// can add another function here
```

Thanks in advance.

Ok so changed code...why does this not work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded

    $('#divright1').click(function(){
        $('#divmainleft').load('sidechange1.php #content', function() })
    $('#divright2').click(function(){
        $('#divmainleft').load('sidechange2.php #content', function() })
    $('#divright3').click(function(){
        $('#divmainleft').load('sidechange3.php #content', function() })
/// can add another function here

}); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
</script>
```

Comment: I've indented your code to show what is nested inside what. Can you see why you need to click `#divright1` first now?

Comment: Made changes to the code to the bet of my limited ability but seems to have killd all JS functionality. Sorry I am really new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors. Fill in the blanks with the code below. You need to close each of your click events and within the callback of the click event you out your load method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //click event and load for div 1
    $('#div1').click(function(){
        $('#mainleft').load('script.php', '#content');
    });

   //click event and load for div 2
    $('#div2').click(function(){
        $('#mainleft2').load('script.php', '#content');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are defining the click function for second and third div inside first div's click function, that's why if first div is clicked then only the click function for second and third div will work.